# django - get latest object with model method in template

Tags: python, django

I have a model with method.

```
class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.TextField() 

class Review(models.Model):
  content = models.TextField()
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book,related_name="book_reviews")  

  def lastreview(self):
    return self.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
```

but once I use this method in template

```
{{book.book_reviews.lastreview.content}}
```

it is showing nothing..

what am i missing here?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the latest object as a context variable in the view?

Comment: @SunnySydeUp, because i am actually rendering many books. i dont want to render their each last reviews separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are trying to retrieve the latest review of a book (which was not clear from your question). The related reviews for a `book` can be accessed by `book.book_reviews`. It is a QuerySet rather than a single `Review` object, hence `{{ book.book_reviews.lastreview }}` will fail.

I would recommend moving the `lastreview` method directly under `Book`, like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()

    def lastreview(self):
        try:
            return self.book_reviews.order_by('-id')[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None
```

Now you can access the latest review of a book in your template by

```
{{ book.lastreview.content }}
```

**Note**: I recommend adding a `DateTimeField` to `Review`, as finding the latest review based on `id` can be misleading. For e.g., someone can edit an old review and it will not be shown as the latest.

Comment: I think I have understood the logic you are trying to implement. Please check my edited answer.